# Android List within a List

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I want to create a dynamic list with separators.

Scenario:User selects a category based on which sub category and sub category items are shown.

```
 Sub Category:
         Item 
         Item
         Item
 Sub Category:
         Item
         Item
```

The number of sub category or items in particular sub categories vary and are generated dynamically.

I have tried with a custom adpater. But the problem is the list becomes jumbled up.

What is the most efficient way to create Lists within List when the lists are generated dynamically?

```
Solution
```

[Use Expandable lists.](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: list within a list is a bad practice and will not work

Comment: Use `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you just use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) ?
here's a good tutorial about it
[Android Expandable List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks, nice example.Let me try this.

Comment: you're welcome,
please accept this as an answer if it helps you solving your problem :)

Comment: The example is perfect and it works... All i have to do is create logic for dynamic sublist and items. Thanks